# Array list returns empty list after i tried to add strings from keyboard

Tags: java, string, arraylist, java.util.scanner

Here in this program, i want to endlessly input strings from the keyboard until the user type in "0". 
I have tried many different combinations of next() and nextLine() but the program either output empty list or did not receive the string.

I have changed the "if condition" 's position from bottom to top within the forever loop. At first, it did not even break out of the loop.

Below is my code:

```
    List<String> keyWords = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println("Input the keywords: (type 0 if you want to stop)\n");
    Scanner scanKeyWords = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(;;) {
        if(scanKeyWords.next().equals("0")) break;
        else
        keyWords.add(scanKeyWords.nextLine());
        System.out.println("done");
    }
    System.out.println(keyWords.toString());
    System.out.println(keyWords.isEmpty());
```

For example when i input 
"Love"
"hate"
"0"
the code returns [, ,]???

I have checked that it is not empty at all with isEmpty?

I'm just a beginner in java. Currently i'm trying to improve my skills by working on this project which is related to keywords.

Could you help me on this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is because you have consumed the input in the `if` condition, so inside the `else` block, nothing will return from `nextLine()`.

This is a working version:

```
import java.util.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> keyWords = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner scanKeyWords = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(;;) {
            String next = scanKeyWords.next();
            if("0".equals(next)) {
                break;
            }
            // if you put keyWords.add(scankeyWords.nextLine()) here, it will not work.
            keyWords.add(next);
        }
        System.out.println(keyWords.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: @SeanWilliam hi, welcome to StackOverflow.   If Surely's answer helped you, you can mark it accepted.